# External video links cannot play in mat-video src using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have installed all the required imports for mat-video to play but still cannot play a video from an extend link or website like youtube or even from my google drive.
Below are the imports i installed from npm,
*@angular/cdk,@angular/material,@angular/animations,hammerjs,mat-video.
All these work perfectly except if i embed a link from my video storage into my src attribute,

This is how am calling mat-video

```
<p>watch works!</p>
<mat-video src={{videoUrl}}>
</mat-video>
```

Below is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-watch',
  templateUrl: './watch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./watch.component.css']
})
export class WatchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  videoUrl:any;
  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.route.paramMap
    .subscribe(params=>
      {
         this.videoUrl =params.get('results')
      })
  }
}
```

Below is json file where i insert the links for my video

```
  {
              "trailerId":3,
              "trailerName":"Bloodshot",
              "date_of_Release":"26-03-2019",
              "trailerVideo":"https://youtu.be/KK8FHdFluOQ",
              "trailerImg":"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSk-Xjs0S4KVnLByZNpAT-oaFmzlcS8xVzJL9sGTXUIRw7s2aMh"
    },
```

Below is the error i get

```
mat-video.js:303 Unhandled Video Error Eventbubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: truecomposed: falsecurrentTarget: nulldefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0isTrusted: truepath: (11) [video.video, div.videoplayer.show-mouse, mat-video, app-watch, div.row, div.container, app-root, body, html, document, Window]returnValue: truesrcElement: video.videotarget: video.videotimeStamp: 4064.0000000003056type: "error"__proto__: Event
callback @ mat-video.js:303
```

[image: The error is get]